# Is there a non-pejorative word for opportunism?

Tags: word-choice

The words "opportunism" and "opportunist" suggest the ability to take advantage of situations -- but they assume that one is doing so for one's own benefit, which makes the terms pejorative.

What is a non-pejorative word in English that means "have the skill and wisdom to recognize and seize opportunities that lead to broad gains"?  I am looking for something that is part of the "art" of diplomacy and politics, for example.

"Clever" is a somewhat helpful adjective, but there is no such thing as a "cleverist."  "Entrepreneur" means is a person who is willing to take on risk and innovate, but lacks the sense of seizing opportunities as they emerge.

It seems like an important concept that has no word.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "go-getter" comes to mind (though i personally don't care for that "word"). it has a positive connotation.

Comment: 'Carpe diemism' (with various spellings) has been used, but if you intend to use the term in formal writing I'd check in OED first.

Comment: You can use any of the suggested terms - *go-getter*, etc., and they are good ones.  But there is a reason that *opportunist* is pejorative. And an opportunist by any other name... ;-)